# How can I compare an image to a set of images to measure similarity in a percentage in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, comparison, analysis

Basically, I would like to load an image onto the app and have it compared to a set of images to determine it's similarity to the group. For example, if i had a group of dog images and uploaded a cat image it would tell me the percentage of whether it is a dog or not?

I've noticed that it might require me to implement some form of algorithm, or even store my image in a cloud.

any helps, tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should start by taking look into machine learning.